# how to use the UINavigationController to switch the page

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to ask a question about the UINavigationController on iPhone application. I create a UINavigationController and 2 view controller (rootViewController.m and detailViewController.m) .In the rootViewController, it contains the UITableView, when the user click, it will call the detailViewController, but I don't know how to do , can anyone teach me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You navigate by simply pushing and popping views.

Pushing and Popping Stack Items
    * – pushViewController:animated:
    * – popViewControllerAnimated:
    * – popToRootViewControllerAnimated:
    * – popToViewController:animated:

Comment: @AivinfromDiaspar, thank you for your reply. And I can call the didSelectRowAtIndexPath for the UITableView now, would you mind to explain more detail?